# Setting attributes of an Hazelcast cluster member

Tags: hazelcast

I have seen that **attribute concept exists in Hazelcast**. I want to define attributes for each member while it is starting and detect which member left the cluster using these attributes.

I could not find how to set it programmatically or by configuration.I tried to get the attributes by the `getAttributes()` method and add a new attribute but it throws an exception since it is an unmodifiable collection.

How can I set attributes of a cluster member?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up attributes in the member configuration and then read them from the client. For example, you can start a Hazelcast cluster in which one member has some attributes assigned and the other does not.

```
// Member with attributes
Config config = new Config();
config.getMemberAttributeConfig().setAttribute("key-1", "value-1");
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

// Member without attributes
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

Then, in the client, you can read the attributes.

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();
for (Member member : client.getCluster().getMembers()) {
    System.out.println("Member attributes: " + member.getAttributes());
}
```

It should print the attributes.

```
Member attributes: {key-1=value-1}
Member attributes: {}
```